# How to graph functions from equations?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Sketch the graph of the following functions:

1. $y= \lvert x-4\rvert -2$
2. $y = \left\{
        \begin{array}{lr}
          x & \text{ if } x <1\\
          x+1 & \text{ if } x >1 \\
          \frac{5}{2} & \text{ if } x = 1\\
        \end{array}
      \right.$
3. $y = \lvert x-1 \rvert + \lvert x+2\rvert$

I am unable to solve these questions please help.

Comment: Please show what you have done so far so that people can better tailor an answer for your specific needs and background. Showing what you've done will also better motivate people to help so they don't think they are just doing your homework.

Comment: Have you tried plugging in various values (negative and positive) of x? This will generate some ordered pairs you can plot. Also, your task will be made easier if 1) you know the definition of absolute value and what the corresponding plot looks like and 2) how the graph of a line works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An absolute value function $y=|x|$ can be graphed using the equivalent piecewise function
$$y=\begin{cases}x& x\geq 0\\-x& x<0\end{cases}$$
meaning that the function $y=|x-4|-2$ can be rewritten as
$$y=\begin{cases}x-6& x\geq 4\\-x+2& x<4\end{cases}$$
To graph a piecewise function, simply take a regular graph of the function and "break it off" wherever it is not defined. For example in the first function $y=|x|$, graph $y=-x$ up until $x=0$ and $y=x$ everywhere else. Your third function can be graphed by looking at the cases where $x<-2$, $-2\leq x\leq 1$, and $1<x$.